# Automatic update of notifications when system language is changed

Tags: android, notifications, android-source

My questions are basically for AOSP code (Android version 4.3).
Questions:
1) When we change system language, already generated notifications are not updated to new language. Is it a bug in Android. If yes, why they are not supporting it(any major problem as such).
Is there any plan for supporting this?
2) If automatic updates are not supported by android, what is the best possible way of doing it?

Awaiting for positive reply on this.

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer.

1. No, it is not a bug and is working as intended I suppose.
   Notification text is **dynamic** and there is no way the OS will know how to translate it automatically. The best thing to do is let the app handle it. I don't think it will be supported.. No at least anytime soon.
2. Best way is to override the onConfigurationChanged method and update all your notifications from within the method.

Comment: Thanks, even I think this is the most appropriate way of doing it right now. I will appreciate if somebody can answer my other questions.